# Random Jlabel image

Tags: java

I've just received a new class project to create Blackjack the card game. No real game play is done yet and I'm just currently working on the user interface.

I am trying to get a random generator that will give the user a random card when the "hit" button is pressed but I need to create some kind of array for images I assume but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

```
public class BlackJack extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    public int card, increase = 1;
    public int cardSlot[] = new int[5];

    ImageIcon cardType = new ImageIcon("E:\\Noahs Coding\\Blackjack\\Cards\\0.gif");

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    BlackJack frame = new BlackJack();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public BlackJack() {

        setTitle("Blackjack");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setBounds(100, 100, 844, 499);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel holder1Card1 = new JLabel("");
        holder1Card1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("E:\\Noahs Coding\\Blackjack\\Cards\\0.gif"));
        holder1Card1.setBounds(0, 295, 73, 222);
        contentPane.add(holder1Card1);

        JLabel holder1Card2 = new JLabel("");
        holder1Card2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("E:\\Noahs Coding\\Blackjack\\Cards\\1.gif"));
        holder1Card2.setBounds(83, 295, 73, 222);
        contentPane.add(holder1Card2);

        JLabel holder1Card3 = new JLabel("");
        holder1Card3.setIcon(new ImageIcon("E:\\Noahs Coding\\Blackjack\\Cards\\2.gif"));
        holder1Card3.setBounds(166, 295, 73, 222);
        contentPane.add(holder1Card3);

        JLabel holder1Card4 = new JLabel("");
        holder1Card4.setIcon(new ImageIcon("E:\\Noahs Coding\\Blackjack\\Cards\\4.gif"));
        holder1Card4.setBounds(249, 295, 73, 222);
        contentPane.add(holder1Card4);

        JLabel holder1Card5 = new JLabel("");
        holder1Card5.setIcon(new ImageIcon("E:\\Noahs Coding\\Blackjack\\Cards\\33.gif"));
        holder1Card5.setBounds(332, 295, 73, 222);
        contentPane.add(holder1Card5);

        JLabel Dealer1 = new JLabel("");
        Dealer1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("E:\\Noahs Coding\\Blackjack\\Cards\\20.gif"));
        Dealer1.setBounds(181, -57, 73, 222);
        contentPane.add(Dealer1);

        JLabel Dealer2 = new JLabel("");
        Dealer2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("E:\\Noahs Coding\\Blackjack\\Cards\\40.gif"));
        Dealer2.setBounds(264, -57, 73, 222);
        contentPane.add(Dealer2);

        JLabel playerNumber = new JLabel("PLAYER HAND");
        playerNumber.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 14));
        playerNumber.setBounds(10, 295, 395, 35);
        contentPane.add(playerNumber);

        JButton hitButton = new JButton("Hit");
        hitButton.setFont(new Font("Yu Gothic UI Semibold", Font.BOLD, 20));
        hitButton.setBounds(428, 398, 140, 50);
        contentPane.add(hitButton);

        JButton standButton = new JButton("Stand");
        standButton.setFont(new Font("Yu Gothic UI Semibold", Font.BOLD, 20));
        standButton.setBounds(578, 398, 140, 50);
        contentPane.add(standButton);

        hitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){


            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                for(; increase < 5;){

                    increase++;

                    System.out.println("slot is equal to: " + increase);

                    break;

                }if (increase == 5){

                    System.out.println("You cannot hit anymore");


                    System.out.println("slot is equal to: " + increase);


                }

            }



        });
    }
}
```

I little look at what the program looks like:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU4PU.png)

I will have the players had empty at the start and every time the "Hit" button is pressed it will add a random card to the players hand. I kinda started creating new **imageicons** but there must be a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some experimenting and I think I came up with a solution!

I'm now calling upon a random number using:

```
                    card = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 52);
```

I've also changed all my Jlabels to:

```
        holder1Card1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("resources\\" + cardNumber + ".gif"));
```

**cardNumber** is a string and I will be setting it up so when **card** is equal to a number, **cardNumber** will be equal to the same.